# Any Islamic ruling on carbon tax?

Tags: halal-haram

Would it be haram to study and devise a carbon tax mechanism?
Carbon tax is the price put on carbon emissions, usually at the national level. But consumers have to pay a part of it and some countries have rebates on them.

Comment: I think it is halal

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please explain why you assume it could be haram. Please share some prior research effort.